# crystal reports differencre in two columns

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a query which is giving a output like below

```
Account    DR Balance    CR Balance
A             1000
A                            2000
B             2000
C             5000
C                            1000
```

I want to display it as below in crystal reports (balance = dr-cr).

```
Account    DR Balance    CR Balance
A                             1000 
B             2000
C             4000
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a formular field on your report. You do that in the Crystal Reports designer.

1. Drag a text object onto your report (from the Tookbox)
2. Right click on the new object and select Edit Formula...
3. The Formula Workshop will appear. In the main text entry panel (its the big panel to the bottom and right) enter in -->

   {MyDataSet.dr} - {MyDataSet.cr}

   Note that the "MyDataSet" is whatever dataset (or view) your Crystal Report is connected to. You should be able to find this in the "Report Fields" that also appears in this window.
4. In the toolbar, click the "X-2" icon which checks that formula is correct. If it fails, then you haven't entered in the correct dataset name/field names.
5. If if validates, click the "Save and close" button.
6. Run your report.